# Performanceoptimized changing of an dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I have a list of dictionaries and I have a solution, described below:

```
[{"A1":"B1", "C1":"D1"},{"A2":"B2", "C2":"D2"},....]
```

Expected output would be a dictionary like this

```
{
"B1":"D1",
"B2":"D2",
...
}
```

My current procedure is
get one dictionary and create a 2 entries dict to a single one

**input:**

```
{"A1":"B1", "C1":"D1"}
```

**output:**

```
{"B1":"D1"}
```

where the "A1" and "C1" is inside my method configureable:

```
def method(input_dictionary, default_key_from_dict, default_value_from_dict):
    single_dictionary[input_dictionary[default_key_from_dict]] =   input_dictionary[default_value_from_dict]
```

later I perform the following ones:

```
def function(dict_list):
    single_key_value_dictionary_list = list(map(convert_two_entries_dictionary_to_one_by_value, dict_list))
    global_dict = reduce(lambda a, b: dict(a, **b), single_key_value_dictionary_list)
    return global_dict
```

I ask myself if there is some better solution for this, I have the generator idea in my mind but I am not sure if it is worth to think about it? Any remarks on this?

**UPDATE**
There are only 2 keys in each entry of the list as dictionary. 2 keys only.

BR Peter

Comment: Does every dictionary in the list have only 2 keys?

Comment: Yes.  2 keys only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments since you always have only 2 keys. You can use `dict.update`.

```
inp=[{"A1":"B1", "C1":"D1"},{"A2":"B2", "C2":"D2"}]
out={}
for d in inp:
    out.update((d.values(),))
out
# {'B1': 'D1', 'B2': 'D2'}
```

Comment: This works great.
Q1: I more or less understand the code, but why did you need the comma here?
Q2:The for loop cannot be avoided as we changes types, right?
Q3: The code complains about incompatible types, despite it is working as expected...

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger To avoid confusion replace `out.update((d.values(),))` with `out.update([d.values()])` the reason is update take a list of key,val pairs i.e `[(k,v),(k1,v1)..]` I used tuple instead of a list

Comment: great, I first changed the code to ... out[list(d.values())[0]] = list(d.values())[1] which works also fine, I do not know which is better regarding performance. Switched back to your suggestion now. Anyway, thank you, I will accept your solution as it is. Despite any more remarks?

Comment: You can use `timeit` for checking performance. @PeterEbelsberger

Comment: '''Unexpected type(s): (List[ValuesView[Union[str, int]]]) Possible types: (Mapping[Union[str, int], Union[str, int]]) (Iterable[Tuple[Union[str, int], Union[str, int]]]) 
 Inspection info: This inspection detects type errors in function call expressions. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Types of function parameters can be specified in docstrings or in Python 3 function annotations.''

    out[list(d.values())[0]] = list(d.values())[1]  # 7.537005509
    out.update([d.values()]) # 5.679888169

yours is better...

Comment: @PeterEbelsberger If it helped please upvote and accept this as answer. Glad to help ;)

Comment: I don't think d.values() is going to have a predictable ordering.  IOW, sometimes you'll get first: last, and other times you'll get last: first.  Should they be sorted somehow?

Comment: It would be fine it is is sorted by the final values. But thats not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something about this:

```
dict1 = {"A1":"B1", "C1":"D1"}
it  = iter(dict1.values())
list1 = list(zip(it, it))
print(list1)
```

Comment: The input is not a dictionary, its a list of dictionaries. This solution does not work for the given input [{"A1":"B1", "C1":"D1"},{"A2":"B2", "C2":"D2"}]